# file not found error when html file is loading

Tags: android, html, webview

//this is from where html file load

```
    progres = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Please wait!", "Loading...");

          web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
          public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String 
          description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progres.dismiss();
            }
        });

        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/sample.html");
      }
   }
```

[image: assets file location]

Comment: Finally,I got solution of my own question, i removed "s" from assets folder path like "file:///android_asset/sample.html"

Answer (score 1):

```
web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/sample.html");
```

android_asset not android_assets

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
    web.loadUrl(getAssets().open("sample.html"));
```